# How can I have relative paths in flash library in order to be able to update all images from any computer?

Tags: image, relative-path, flash-cs4

I would like to ask how can I use relative paths in flash library in order to be able to update images from any computer? I use Flash CS4. I tried to import images from File->Import->Import to Library but i stil get absolute path...

Thanks!